# Can't get the most common word

Tags: awk

I need to get all words with one vowel from a file and print one the most common of them. I use awk for matching one-vowel words, but I don't know how to get the most common one.

For example, for text `test qwerty word test The result is test`, it should print `test`.

Here is my awk-script:

```
BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1; }
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        pattern = "\\<[^AEYUIO]*[AEYUIO][^AEYUIO]*\\>" # pattern for one-vowel words
        if($i ~ pattern){
                print $i
        }
    }
}
```

It prints all the one-vowel words, now I need to get the most common of them. I tried to use `sort` like this: `awk -f script file_with_data | sort`, but I didn't find which parameters to use. Help me, please.

Comment: @Cyrus I do not agree with your edit! I need to sort the words, but I don't know with which utility. I gave an example with `sort` utility, so it isn't only-awk question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1; }
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        pattern = "\\<[^AEYUIO]*[AEYUIO][^AEYUIO]*\\>" # pattern for one-syllable words
        if($i ~ pattern){
            if(++freq[$i]>maxf){                       # keep word count and compare
                maxw=$i
                maxf=freq[$i]
            }
        }
    }
}
END{
    print maxw
}' file
```

Output:

```
test
```

If there are equal counts for several words this only prints one, in that case and since you are already using GNU awk (`IGNORECASE`):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1; }
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        pattern = "\\<[^AEYUIO]*[AEYUIO][^AEYUIO]*\\>" # pattern for one-syllable words
        if($i ~ pattern)
            freq[$i]++                                 # word frequencies
    }
}
END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_type_desc"             # arm for sorting order
    for(w in freq)                                     # get biggest count
        if(freq[w]>=p) {                               # and equal counts
            print w
            p=freq[w]
        } else
            break
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use awk?
Otherwise you could get it with a mix of `grep` and `uniq -c` like:

```sh
% echo test qwerty word test The result is test | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -iE "^[^AEYUIO]*[AEYUIO][^AEYUIO]*$" | sort | uniq -c | sort
1 is
1 The
1 word
3 test
```

Comment: Yes, I have to do it with awk but your answer helped me. I did `awk -f script  file_with_data | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head -n 1` and it prints what I want!
Thanks!